# my app crashes eveytime I try to use app.use

Tags: javascript, routes

My code crashes every time I try to use routes in my main file. Here is the code, my main file and my route file. Does anyone know what is wrong ?

Index.js file

```
    const express = require('express');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const routes =require('./routes');

    const app = express();
    mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://usuario:senha@cluster0-d7oad.mongodb.net/week10?retryWrites=true&w=majority',{
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    });

    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(routes); 
    app.listen(3333);
```

routes.js file:

```
    const { Router } = require ('express');

    const routes = Router ();

    routes.post('/devs',(request,response) => { 
        //console.log(request.body);
        const { github_username} =request.body; 
        return response.json({message: 'Hello! Noooott'});
    });

    module.export = routes;
```

Comment: add code instead of images

Comment: I think you might need something like this "app.use(something)", because it says "required a middelware function".

Comment: So either remove the line or give it a middelware as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a typo in `route.js`

`model.exports` needs `s`

```
    module.exports = routes;
```